# Is it possible to stop selected plugins from loading on certain template pages?

Tags: plugins, theme-development, templates, page-template

I have a template page that has form on that is only used once in my site. The form uses form validation using [jquery validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) (such a great plugin). Once the cart66 Plugin is loaded, the form validation stops working.

Rather spending ages looking for the conflict, I thought it would be easiest to just turn off the plugin for that template page as cart66 is not need on this page.

Is it possible to stop plugins loading on individual template pages? I am using WordPress 3.2.1

Answer (score 3):

Use Plugin Organizer.  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/plugin-organizer/.  It cant disable plugins by template but it can disable them by post, page, custom post_type, or arbitrary URL.

Comment: its a good plugin but it will not replace the code level editing, the plugin is good but not as efficient as manual editing

Comment: The problem with manual code way is you have to do a lot of detective work to figure out resource names and such. What if you miss something? Whaat is the plugin gets an update and a resource is changed or added? You have to constantly double-check your manual code? Meanwhile with a plugin organizer everything is automatic.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the javascript from cart66 and your form plugin are in conflict. You can 'turn off' javascript per page/ post etc. by using the enqueue script function.

Hopefully both of your plugins are written well and include their javascript with this method.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

If so, they will have a handle that you can use to deregister (or dequeue) the script.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script

You'll need to write a conditional script

```
<?php if(!is_page('FORM-PAGE-SLUG')){wp_dequeue('form-javascript-handle')}?>
```

that should be a good starting place.

Comment: Thanks already thought of searching for all the scripts that Cart66 includes and using enqueue to stop them. Would be nice if there was a way to just turn on the plugin all together.

Comment: That may not be possible, especially with an e-commerce plugin - there may be session data or other variables that need to be carried by functions throughout the entire site visit that you would lose by dropping functions. If anything, the best solution is to find out what is conflicting with form javascript. What errors are you getting in Firebug when you try to use the form?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can disable specific plugins or scripts form appearing on certain pages.

Check this example how [I disabled the easy fancybox plugin from appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774424/wordpress-disable-plugin-on-specific-pages-posts/6981957#6981957)

Hope it helps :)