# How do i 'deactivate' a plugin only on a certain page template?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, headers

I have a plugin which is great but it's kind of aggressive, and it changes a lot more than it should (but there are no settings to fix this).

I have a custom page template that calls wp_head('less') ... header-less.php, and i have an equivalent for footer-less.php.

I basically want, in this custom header-less.php to DE-REGISTER the plugin immediately after it gets registered.

note that i dont want to DeACTIVATE the plugin, because i really need the functionality on the other page templates, only on this certain template do I want to basically 'destroy' the plugin or deactivate it somehow

Comment: Usually, you can tell WordPress which hooks/filters to remove... what plugin are you using and what functionality are you trying to disable in this template?

Comment: http://pastie.org/4028253 - it's called trueEdit. It basically removes all of wordpress's annoying autoformatting options. The problem is it removes the helpful ones too. So really I want to only have the plugin load on a certain page template (where i will be copying and pasting html anyway).

Comment: or rather... id like to de-register that plugin via unregistering the hook or whatever i need to do

Comment: A similar question, unanswered: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24710/is-it-possible-to-stop-selected-plugins-from-loading-on-certain-template-pages :(

Comment: :( so... yeah, i hope someone knows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick glance at that plugin shows that it loads the filters from an option, `trueedit_options`. You might be able to add a filter to `option_trueedit_options` and check the context of when that option is being loaded and return an empty array. It runs on `init` though, so not sure how you'd determine that.

Another option is to add the filters back on in your header file. If you look in `/wp-includes/default-filters.php` you'll see all of the filters that are added to the content which could potentially be removed by the plugin:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize'        );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_smilies'    );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_chars'      );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop'            );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop'  );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prepend_attachment' );
```